# ¿Como renombrar ficheros sin necesidad de duplicarlos en la máquina?

Tags: java

Estoy subiendo ficheros a un servidor por medio de php y java. Tengo una clase en java que me ayuda en esto mediante Post. Puedo subir ficheros correctamente y acceder a ellos pero en algunas ocasiones estos contienen acentos y caracteres especiales que el servidor de Apache no reconoce y por tanto termina cambiando su nombre. Esto provoca que al buscar el fichero mediante el nombre que almacene en la base datos no pueda acceder a el.

Este es el nombre original y el resultado en el servidor:

> - alas número 1.jpeg
> - alas nÃºmero 1.jpeg

Para evitar esto quiero modificar el nombre del fichero a subir desde java con:

```
URLEncoder.encode("alas número 1.jpeg", "UTF-8");
```

De esta manera ya no tendría problemas con mis ficheros. El meollo del asunto radica en que no puedo cambiar el nombre del fichero con File sin crear otro fichero o no he podido encontrar como hacerlo.

Prácticamente lo que hago es esto:

```
public class FicherosOperaciones {

/**
 * Duplica el fichero que se le pase y lo retorna como parametro. 
 */
public static File duplicar(File ficheroACopiar){

    FileInputStream in = null;
    int aleatorio = (int) (Math.random()*2);
    File ficheroDestino = new File(ficheroACopiar.getAbsolutePath()+aleatorio);
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(ficheroACopiar);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(ficheroDestino);
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read())!= -1) {
            out.write(c);
        }   
        in.close();
        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FicherosOperaciones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FicherosOperaciones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FicherosOperaciones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    //ficheroDestino.deleteOnExit();
    return ficheroDestino;

}


/**
 * Duplica un fichero y lo renombra para que coincida con UTF-8.
 * @param fichero
 * @return 
 */
public static File duplicarUTF8(File fichero){
    File duplicado=null;
    try {
        String ruta = fichero.getParent();
        String nombreUTF8 = URLEncoder.encode(fichero.getName(), "UTF-8");
        File ficheroRenombrado = new File(ruta+System.getProperty("file.separator")+nombreUTF8);
        duplicado = duplicar(fichero);
        duplicado.renameTo(ficheroRenombrado);
        return ficheroRenombrado;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FicherosOperaciones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FicherosOperaciones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return duplicado;

}
```

}

El código duplica el fichero, lo renombra y despues lo retorna para utilizarlo. Mi plan es subirlo al servidor y eliminarlo. Pero el proceso de copiado es muy lento si tuviera que subir 10 o 15 archivos. ¿Hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo más rápido?

No quiero perder el fichero original ni modificarlo, pero a la hora de subir al servidor quiero que tenga el nombre nuevo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> el proceso de copiado es muy lento

Es lento porque el algoritmo que usas copia byte por byte de un archivo a otro, lo que hace que el proceso sea lento. Esto se nota aquí:

```
//aquí ocupas 1 byte
int c;
while ((c = in.read())!= -1) {
    out.write(c);
}
```

En lugar de copiar 1 a 1, lo que puedes hacer es copiar un lote (chunk) de bytes, usualmente de 4KBs u 8 KBs. Esto lo puedes lograr usando las clases `BufferedInputStream` y `BufferedOutputStream`:

```
static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 4 * 1024; //4 Kbytes

//try-with-resources de Java 7
try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(ficheroACopiar));
     BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(ficheroDestino))) {
    byte[] chunk = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
    int leidos;
    while ((leidos = bis.read(chunk))!= -1) {
        out.write(chunk, 0, leidos);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FicherosOperaciones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Si usas Java 7 o superior, también puedes optar por usar [`Files#copy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) que usa una estrategia similar.

Comment: Impresionante. Me decante por la opción de `Files.copy()` y lo hizo muy rápido. Muchas gracias.